# Can determine length of the variable by incoming?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to the length of the variable str determine when incoming ?

```
int i = 0;
char str[؟؟];
cin >> str;
cout << str;
```

Comment: If you are a mindreader, yes.

Comment: What is `int i = 0;` for in your code?

Comment: Why not use a string

Comment: int i = 11 ; when i worked on them changed to 0

Comment: This is a university question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not.

That is the reason people use `std::string` instead of manually fumbling around with character arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

No. You should use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.